# C structures string reading error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct person {
    char name[50];
    int id;
    int age;
};

int main() {
    struct person p[4];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("Enter the person%d details\n", i + 1);
        gets(p[i].name);
        scanf("%d", &p[i].id);
        scanf("%d", &p[i].age);
    }
    printf(
        "------------------------------------------------------------------");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("\nPerson%d details\n", i + 1);
        printf("Name:%s\nID:%d\nAge:%d\n", p[i].name, p[i].id, p[i].age);
        printf("---------------------------------------------------------------"
               "---");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter person1 details
mark mike
123
24

Enter person2 details
sourav ganguly
Enter person3 details
```

The problem is why `scanf` is not accepting `person2 id and age` details. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Frequent duplicate — there are lots of equivalent questions for the same problem.  The `%d` formats leave the newline in the buffer, and the `gets()` (which should ***NOT*** be being used in the first place — use `fgets()` instead) reads that newline as the whole line.  You'd know more if you paid attention to the return values from your input functions too — you can't afford not to check input functions.

Answer (score 0):

The `new-line` character that follows the `24` input on the very first iteration of the cycle is not read by `scanf`. It is left in the input stream by the last `scanf` on iteration for person #1.

On the next iteration that pending `new-line` character is read by `gets` and is interpreted as an empty string, an empty name for person #2. The program then waits for your input. You assume that it waits for the name of person #2, but in reality it waits on `scanf` for the `id` of person #2. You enter `sourav ganguly` (falsely believing that you are entering a name), but this is seen by `scanf` as incorrect input for `%d` format specifier. This results in both `scanf`s for person #2 getting skipped with garbage in `id` and `age` of person #2. Meanwhile, `sourav ganguly` remains in the input stream.

On the next iteration, `sourav ganguly` is finally read by `gets` as the name of person #3. And so on...

If you prepend each of your `scanf`'s with an additional debugging `printf`'s, you will see what is actually going on. E.g. try this and see what happens

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("Enter the person%d name\n", i + 1);
    gets(p[i].name);
    printf("Enter the person%d id\n", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &p[i].id);
    printf("Enter the person%d age\n", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &p[i].age);
}
```

The best way to fix it is to stop the attempts to mix `gets` and `scanf` input. One way to fix it is to read all data as strings and then parse it manually. Another way to fix it is to get rid of `gets` and use `scanf` instead. `scanf` can be used to read strings with spaces in them, but it won't look pretty. Anyway, `scanf` docs will help you to figure this out. (Hint: read about `%[]` format specifier.)

In any case `gets` function should not be used, since it provides no protection from buffer overflow.